# Regex, how to match everything up to nth occurrence

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get everything from a webpage up until the second occurrence of a word `matchdate`.

`(.*?matchdate){2}`   is what I'm trying but that's not doing that trick. The page has 14+ matches of "matchdate" and I only want to get everything up to the second one, and then nothing else.

https://regex101.com/r/Cjyo0f/1  <--- my saved regex.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Split the string with your `matchdate` and then join the first two items.

Comment: Turn off the `g` (global) flag.

Comment: @Bahnzo See my new answer below.  Your regex was already correct and didn't need any of the suggested changes.  It is a simple flag fix that makes the dot work as you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this:

#### If you can, remove the `g` flag

Without the global flag, regex will only grab the first instance it encounters.

https://regex101.com/r/Cjyo0f/2

#### Add a `^` to the front of the regex

A caret will force the regex to match from the beginning of the string, ruling out all other possibilities.

https://regex101.com/r/Cjyo0f/3

#### If Python is available, use `.split()` and `.join()`

If regular python is available, I would recommend:

```
string = "I like to matchdate, I want to each matchdate for breakfest"
print "matchdate".join(string.split("matchdate")[:2])
```

Comment: In the tool that I'm using I don't have that ability.

Comment: I added another method, will that one do?

Comment: I added another regex solution, add a `^` to the front.

Comment: I could've sworn I tried the carret in front. I guess not... :)

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it!  `(.*?matchdate){2}` was actually correct.  It just needs a [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag so that the dot matches newlines as well as other characters.

Here is a working test:

```
>>> import re

>>> s = '''First line
Second line
Third with matchdate and more
Fourth line
Fifth with matchdate and other
stuff you're
not interested in
like another matchdate
or a matchdate redux.
'''

>>> print(re.search('(.*?matchdate){2}', s, re.DOTALL).group())
First line
Second line
Third with matchdate and more
Fourth line
Fifth with matchdate
```